# What factors would make it likely / unlikely that a government would want to and be capable of hiding known alien activity?

Tags: earth

This question is pretty simple, based on Earth, with modern governments. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYzRY2XpLBk) of President Obama on Jimmy Kimmel is for fun, but it still made me wonder.

What factors would make it likely / unlikely that a government would want to and be capable of hiding known alien activity?

I'm interested in logical, political, and technological factors that we can draw from to get a good idea for whether it would make any sense for such a thing to be hidden.

Comment: Why would *all* governments agree to universally hide it?

Comment: Because the government is being "body snatched" term after term?

Comment: I fear this question is too broad. "What kind of alien activity are they trying to hide?" If the answer is a big crash in a major metro area, the answer is never. But high altitude passes detectable only by nuclear attack early warning radar, the answer could be "quite a while".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This report](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0147905) concludes that any large scale conspiracy will fail within a very short time-frame, based on analysis of past conspiracies. So unless you happen to believe that this report was produced as the result of a conspiracy, the indicated course of action would be to not suppress knowledge of any known alien activity.

Comment: Well, you are basing this off of the conspiracies that have failed and therefore been discovered. The ones that succeed are the ones you don't know about. Your answer essentially says, based on past failed conspiracies, yours wil fail fairly quickly.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon I read it as, due to a common phenomenon where the more people know about it, the harder it is to hide, we can deduce the likelihood of information of such magnitude being hidden, which would require at least a dozen personnel,  is very low. Makes sense to me.. The only issue at all is that this answer doesn't elaborate very well into the "worldbuilding" answer model, like the one below. But the people here closed my question, so Ill just accept an answer and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Likely**

- If it holds some technology that could be a great danger to the region / country / world / the very fabric of space and time. Compare to [the Non-Proliferation Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons). It concludes "Sure, we know the secret of making big radioactive booms, but we trust ourselves to not be irresponsible with it. The rest of the world however... hmmm... not so much".

**Unlikely (or rather: likely to reveal)**

- If it holds some secret that is of such great benefit to the world it drastically improves the safety and security of the world, such as free, clean energy. Compare the [Atoms For Peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoms_for_Peace) program where the US made the [light-water nuclear reactor design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-water_reactor) available to the world since the LWR was an inherently safe(r) design compared to others that were on the drawing-board, such as the [Soviet RBMK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RBMK), which went *ka-boom* in Chernobyl 30 years ago this month.